# sendEmail messages not being received by Exchange server

Tags: php, craft3

I've been able to get this to work with my gmail address but not my work's Exchange email account. How can I make this receivable by exchange mail servers?

```
    $email = new EmailModel();
    $email->toEmail = 'EMAILADDRESS';
    $email->subject = 'test';
    $email->body    = 'test';

    $sent = craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
```

Comment: Total guess here, but it could be a case of the Exchange server is flagging the email as spam. How are you sending the mail? I've found/had good luck in the past using SMTP. Something like SendGrid or Mandril

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Damon.  I use Exchange and haven't noticed any issues with receiving emails (either from Craft system or withing my own plugins).  I am using Mandrill to send them.  You might have greater success if you fill out more of the model (fromEmail etc) but more than likely it's using php mail that is the core issue.

Email deliverability is these days a complex thing, much better to leave it to the experts, although for best results even then you still need to pay attention to your Mandrill & domain setups (SPF/DKIM etc).